# Like button of a specific Wordpress article should refer to a specific Facebook post

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-like

I have a website and a facebook page, that relates to it.
When I create an article on my Wordpress blog it gets shared on Facebook too.

To increase the number of subscribers of my FB page, I want to create a Like button below my article, which likes the related Facebook post.

Is this possible? Can this be done using a plugin or coding?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why all the answers in here just try to explain how to create Like Buttons in general, but you can´t use the Like Button for a Facebook Object (and THAT is what you want to do, right?). Well, you can, but only for a Facebook Page - not for entries in the timeline of a User or Page.

There may be one possibility by using [og.likes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/og.likes), but every User would have to authorize an App for that and you would need to go through a review process on Facebook.

Anyway, you should not use more than one Like Button per article, and you should add the article permalink as href value in the Like Button - else it would be weird for the User. He wants to like the article, not an entry on a Facebook Wall. And - of course - you can´t (and shouldn´t) Like 2 different things at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Have a look at [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/).

It will let you copy and paste some code into your blog that will give you a row of sharing buttons - when you set up the sharing it should give you an option to tell it which URL you would like to share.

They also have a Wordpress plugin, but that will just share the URL of the post/page you're on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Facebook provides a Social Plugins options which you can include in your website, you need to include the following javascript code in your particular page inside the body tag

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=546676442100387&version=v2.0";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and Place the following code for your plugin wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

For further details you can goto the following link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button   hope it helps..

Note: You need to replace the link in the data-href  by your particular webpage link